# Can I get an 8-bit clean connection with 'socat'?

Tags: virtualbox, tty, modem

This question is mostly about "socat", but here's some background to go with it:

I am trying -- for reasons having mostly to do with nostalgia -- to write a virtual modem driver for use with VirtualBox.  It should listen to the socket that VirtualBox connects to the virtual guest, and emulate (a) a standard Hayes command set and (b) let one connect to remote systems using "atd some.host.name".  Mostly it works, but I've run into problems with data transfers.  I assume the problem is mine, because I seldom have the chance to muck about with mult-channel communication, select loops, and the like...

...so I though I would prototype my solution using the "socat" command, like this:

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/vbox.port EXEC:"telnet -E8 some.remote.host"
```

This works, sort of, just like my solution -- basic interactive typing seems fine, but try a file transfer and it just falls over.  I've also tried this, just in case there was some sort of tty line discipline in the way:

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/vbox.port EXEC:"telnet -E8 some.remote.host",pty,raw,cs8
```

That didn't work any better.

I'm wondering if anyone here has thoughts on solving this.  The problem is not with telnet; using `-E8` provides an 8-bit clean path that works fine by itself (e.g., when not involved in this sort of pty-proxying).

This is obviously not a critical problem, but I'm hoping that someone else out there finds it at least mildly interesting.

Comment: I don't think `socat` has any problem with arbitrary byte streams, so I suspect the fault is elsewhere. Can you post a small reproducible example?

Comment: @Gilles: (1) Install DOS under virtualbox and assign com1 to a socket on the remote host.  (2) Install a terminal program; [txzm](http://goo.gl/2Nrs9) seems like a nice one.  (3) Connect the com1 socket to a remote host using `socat`.  (4) Try to transfer a file with zmodem (e.g., using `sz` from the lrzsz package).

Comment: ...noting, again, that I'm not suggesting you actually go through any of this unless you find this problem interesting.

Comment: I might try it if I could do Linux to Linux, but DOS? No way. Though what's DOS for anyway? I do have a Linux VM on Linux.

Comment: You could probably demonstrate the problem using minicom on Linux, too.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say telnet is not the culprit, I would test taking it away.

Have you tried the following?

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/vbox.port tcp:some.remote.host:23
```

This should be 8-bit clean by itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, telnet is required, and demonstrably is not the problem -- for example, one can use [qodem](http://qodem.sourceforge.net/) over a telnet connection without a hitch.  I'm beginning to suspect the VirtualBox socket itself, but I'm not sure exactly how to verify that.  A simple "send characters 0x00 through 0xFF" seems to work as expected.